# count all the id elements from page using jquery length function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all the id elements used in a page using jquery lenth function.
like $(".class").length;
Want to get for id

Comment: $('[id]').length

Comment: And, without jQuery: `document.querySelectorAll('[id]').length`

Comment: A thing to note would be using the 'Vanilla' javascript version David posted will be a lot less resource heavy. Not much difference in many use cases, but min-maxing is a thing :)

Answer (score 4):

According to [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

> jQuery( "[attribute]" ):  Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value

Therefore, the following line of code will get all elements having an id attribute

```
$('[id]').length
```

Comment: can at least add the jQuery doc reference? Thanks

Comment: @gaetanoM: *what* jQuery doc reference? It's a CSS Selector (as most jQuery selectors are).

Comment: [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), [jQuery's Has Attribute Selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

Answer (score -1):

You are not allowed to have more then 1 element with the same id

Comment: Please provide answer. If you want to ask any question/suggestion then please use comment section.

Comment: I was not able to use the comments section as my reputation points was low. Thanks for making it even lower.

Comment: I got the answer

Comment: $('[id^=idName]').length

Comment: I was trying to get all the elements finally we can achieve it by using    $('[id^=idName]').length

Comment: @FirozaShaikh is there any specific reason why you are using multiple elements with same id? As per W3 specifications, id should be unique.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_id.asp